# Changing values of a column in a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame exemplified as

```
data = [['A', 10, {'Cc', 'Dd'}], ['B', 15, {'Aa', 'Dd', 'Cc', 'Ee'}],
        ['C', 14, {'Dd', 'Ee', 'Aa'}],['D', 3, {'Bb'}],['E', 3,{'Dd', 'Cc'}]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['type', 'val', 'others'])
```

I would like to perform some data processing on this dataset. For the 'type' column, I have introduced a dictionary as

```
dic_type ={'A':0, 'B':1, 'C':2, 'D':3, 'E':4}
```

which brings the first column into a value using

```
df["type"].replace(dic_type, inplace=True)
```

This column then looks good to me to carry out the rest of the analysis. However, I am unsure how to bring the values of the 'others' column into numbers.

Each cell of the last column contains a list with various numbers of elements. The permutation of these elements, which may appear in some cells, should not be counted. For instance, the values for the first and last cell of the 'others' should be identical.
Do you have any suggestions on getting this enumeration?
My data frame has over 6000 cells, and I should perform this task as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to assign a numerical code to the column `others` - which contains sets of values.

You can convert the column values to `frozenset` and then apply `pd.Categorical` to it:

```py
df["others_codes"] = pd.Categorical(df["others"].apply(frozenset)).codes
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  type  val            others  others_codes
0    A   10          {Dd, Cc}             0
1    B   15  {Dd, Aa, Ee, Cc}             2
2    C   14      {Dd, Ee, Aa}             1
3    D    3              {Bb}             3
4    E    3          {Dd, Cc}             0
```